# Tableadapter.Update not able to search a row to update

Tags: mysql, vb.net, tableadapter

My database has a table that has no primary key and rows are identified as a combination of column values - *Memeber_Id* & *Book_Id*.

I want to update a third column in the table after identifying the row, but not sure how to do that. I want to use something like this-

```
TableAdapter.Update(Member_Id, Book_Id, New_Value_for_third_Column)
```

Please let me know if there is any solution to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy, I had the same problem... I could solve it by adding a primary key to the table in the mySQL table.

Also: 
Tableadapter.Update(YOUR DATASET.YOUR DATA TABLE)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z16c79x4(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. I know adding primary key has its own advantages, but I was looking more towards getting a solution that doesn't involve modifying the database. Can you suggest something in that direction as well?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a primary key, the answer to your question can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tat996zc.aspx